# Como Trabalhar com objeto em javascript

Tags: javascript, java, view, objetos

Bem estou tento dificuldades para entender como trabalhar com um objeto que vem do meu controller no javascript, já realizei alguns testes para ter certeza que essa informação subiu de forma correta para o view porem, não entendi como trabalhar essa informação no javascript se alguém poder ajudar ficarei grato.

segue o controller que utilizo para subir o lista de objeto

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/show/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewPesquisar(@PathVariable("id") Long id, ModelMap 
    model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    LOGGER.debug(" O id a ser consultado é {}", id);

    List<Ito> optional = itoService.findByIdFetchAll(id);

    if (optional.isEmpty()) {

        LOGGER.debug(" Não foi possivel localizar o Tipo com o Id:{}", id);

        throw new BusinessException("Não foi possivel Localizar o Tipo de Projeto");
    }

    List<Ito> listaCompletaItos = itoService.findByIdFetchAll(id);

    model.addAttribute("listaCompletaItos", listaCompletaItos);

    return new ModelAndView(REQUEST_MAPPING_PAGE_SHOW_ITO);
}
```

eu mando a informação para o view através do ModelAndview não sei dizer se é a melhor forma nesse caso.

Comment: Não tem como você ter um `controller no javascript` uma vez que [tag:javascript] é uma linguagem client-side executada pelo Browser.

Comment: certo a questão é como posso trabalhar essa lista dentro do javascript

Answer (score 0):

Voce tem duas formas de fazer isso! Uma é escrevendo essa informacao no header da tua página como uma variável JavaScript e a outra é puxando via ajax do JavaScript para o teu controler! Só depois de decidires qual vais usar e que posso lhe ajudar